# How to get the total working hours for employees with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an attendance table for the employees like the following

```
ID     Employee-ID       Date      Coming-time  Leaving-time   Break(in hours)
1         1             2016-01-01   08:00:00     18:30:00       0,50 
2         1             2016-01-02   20:00:00     08:00:00       1,50
3         1             2016-01-03   18:30:00     06:00:00       1,50
4         1             2016-01-04   08:00:00     18:30:00       0,00
```

How can I calculate the total working hours for each employee for a each month without the breaks.....

The problem is with DATEDIFF for hours not giving me true value for when having half hours, for example the following query:

```
ID     Employee-ID       Month      TotalHours  WorkingTime   
1        1                12            10          9,5     
2        1                12            12          10,5     
3        1                12            12          10,5     
4        1                12            10          10
```

as you can see the TotalHours is wrong where the values should be like this

```
TotalHours
   10,5
   12
   11,5
   10,5
```

The query I am trying is like this: (Thanks for the help from answers and comments ...)

```
(SELECT ID, Employee-ID, MONTH(Date) AS Month,
CASE
    WHEN Coming-time > Leaving-time THEN  DATEDIFF(HOUR, Leaving-time, Coming-time) 
    WHEN Coming-time <= Leaving-time THEN   DATEDIFF(HOUR, Coming-time, Leaving-time)  
END AS TotalHours,
CASE
    WHEN Coming-time > Leaving-time THEN  DATEDIFF(HOUR, Leaving-time, Coming-time) - Break 
    WHEN Coming-time <= Leaving-time THEN   DATEDIFF(HOUR, Coming-time, Leaving-time) - Break
END as WorkingTime
FROM      TblEmployee)
```

How can I get a true value for the total hours?

Comment: you notice that the coming-time in rows 2 and 3 are bigger than the leaving-time? which brings a possible flaw in...are these really on the same date, or do you assume if leaving is less than coming then its the next day? not to mention if this is all the same employee id then you got some funny business going on in time reporting

Comment: @hubson-bropa you are true, my mistake sorry
the dates are for different dates, thanks for noticing...

Comment: What are each column's data type? Is the comma in `break` just a  localized output or the actual content in a string column.

Comment: @adrianm the Break column type is Decimal, Coming-time  and Leaving-time columns type are Time, and Month column type is Date ...

Comment: Datediff only looks at the hour value. (i.e. datediff(hour, 9:59, 11:01) => 11 - 9 = 2). What you need to do is to use datediff(minute, .. and divide result by 60)

Comment: @LFB it may not be your mistake. That is a perfectly valid sceanrio where someone comes to work before midnight and leaves the next day. Point is if you can change the data model then make the coming/leaving datetimes and this gets alot easier...then your jsut doing straight date diffs. if not then you might want to just make the assumption that its next day. this will greatly change the query.

Answer (score 3):

You ever see that iceberg poster, the one where 80% is underwater so you don't consider it.

Your question is a lot like that. It looks innocuous, and yet just out of initial glance there is a hidden beast. In this case, that beast is the data structure you're having to do this for plus the fact that shifts appear to cross days. Short story here's you iceberg solution in SQL. Long story below that.

[image]

```
SELECT
    base.[Employee-ID],
    DATEPART(year, base.[Date]) AS [Year],
    DATEPART(month, base.[Date]) AS [Month],
    DATEPART(day, base.[Date]) AS [Day],
    SUM(base.HoursWorked) AS TotalHoursAtWork,
    SUM(base.HoursOnBreak) AS TotalBreakHours,
    SUM(base.HoursWorked) - SUM(base.HoursOnBreak) AS TotalHoursWorked
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [Employee-ID],
        CAST(StartDateTime AS DATE) [Date],
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
                DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, StartDateTime), 1)) / 60.0
        END HoursWorked,
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
                BreakHours
            ELSE
                BreakHours / 2
        END HoursOnBreak
    FROM (
        SELECT
            [ID],
            [Employee-ID],
            [Date],
            [Coming-time],
            [Leaving-time],
            [Break(in hours)] AS BreakHours,
            CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Coming-time] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartDateTime,
            CASE
                WHEN [Coming-time] <= [Leaving-time] THEN 
                    CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
                ELSE
                    CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, [Date]) AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
            END AS EndDateTime
        FROM
            [sandbox].[dbo].[TblEmployee]
    ) AS firstDay
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [Employee-ID],
        CAST(EndDateTime AS DATE) [Date],
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
                0
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, EndDateTime), 0), EndDateTime) / 60.0
        END HoursWorked,
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
                0
            ELSE
                BreakHours / 2
        END HoursOnBreak
    FROM (
        SELECT
            [ID],
            [Employee-ID],
            [Date],
            [Coming-time],
            [Leaving-time],
            [Break(in hours)] AS BreakHours,
            CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Coming-time] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartDateTime,
            CASE
                WHEN [Coming-time] <= [Leaving-time] THEN 
                    CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
                ELSE
                    CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, [Date]) AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
            END AS EndDateTime
        FROM
            [sandbox].[dbo].[TblEmployee]
    ) AS secondDay
) AS base
GROUP BY
    base.[Employee-ID],
    DATEPART(year, base.[Date]),
    DATEPART(month, base.[Date]),
    DATEPART(day, base.[Date])
```

So why all this stuff? The problem is time reporting in a date and time is fundamentally flawed. It's really about number of hours worked into some bucket, like per day, per task, per project, etc.

Since you are trying to look at the number of hours worked per day / month / year then we just have to take this data and put it in the lowest common denominator, hours per day.

Step 1 - Get the coming and leaving into datetime format. Which gets us to equal data type and, incidentally, shows what happens when coming time is greater than leaving.

[image]

```
SELECT
    [ID],
    [Employee-ID],
    [Date],
    [Coming-time],
    [Leaving-time],
    [Break(in hours)],
    CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Coming-time] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartDateTime,
    CASE
        WHEN [Coming-time] <= [Leaving-time] THEN 
            CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
        ELSE
            CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, [Date]) AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
    END AS EndDateTime
FROM
    [sandbox].[dbo].[TblEmployee]
```

Step 2 - Now that we've got true representation of datetimes, convert to hours per day. Problem is shifts sometimes cross days. ruh roh raggy.

So lets split it out and in multi day shitfs lets half the break to each day.

WARNING: Assumptions:

- If coming time is 'after' (hour:minute is more than) leaving then leaving is assumed to be the time during the next day.
- A shitft is never longer than 24 hours. If someone one comes in at 8am and leaves at 10am it is assumed to be 2 hours, not 26. Such is life if you do not have a date for leaving.
- Breaks are not always going to be half and half so some
  variation there.

[image]

```
SELECT
    [Employee-ID],
    CAST(StartDateTime AS DATE) FirstDay,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
            DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, StartDateTime), 1)) / 60.0
    END FirstDayHours,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
            BreakHours
        ELSE
            BreakHours / 2
    END FirstDayBreak,
    CAST(EndDateTime AS DATE) SecondDay,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
            0
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, EndDateTime), 0), EndDateTime) / 60.0
    END SecondDayHours,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
            0
        ELSE
            BreakHours / 2
    END SecondDayBreak
FROM (
    SELECT
        [ID],
        [Employee-ID],
        [Date],
        [Coming-time],
        [Leaving-time],
        [Break(in hours)] AS BreakHours,
        CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Coming-time] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartDateTime,
        CASE
            WHEN [Coming-time] <= [Leaving-time] THEN 
                CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
            ELSE
                CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, [Date]) AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
        END AS EndDateTime
    FROM
        [sandbox].[dbo].[TblEmployee]
) AS base
```

Step 3 - Problem is we need these in a single day column to group by. The union below just separates out the logic for first and second day into two separate queries. Efficient = hell no, functional - yes.

[image]

```
SELECT
    [Employee-ID],
    CAST(StartDateTime AS DATE) [Date],
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
            DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, StartDateTime), 1)) / 60.0
    END HoursWorked,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
            BreakHours
        ELSE
            BreakHours / 2
    END HoursOnBreak
FROM (
    SELECT
        [ID],
        [Employee-ID],
        [Date],
        [Coming-time],
        [Leaving-time],
        [Break(in hours)] AS BreakHours,
        CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Coming-time] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartDateTime,
        CASE
            WHEN [Coming-time] <= [Leaving-time] THEN 
                CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
            ELSE
                CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, [Date]) AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
        END AS EndDateTime
    FROM
        [sandbox].[dbo].[TblEmployee]
) AS firstDay
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [Employee-ID],
    CAST(EndDateTime AS DATE) [Date],
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
            0
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, EndDateTime), 0), EndDateTime) / 60.0
    END HoursWorked,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
            0
        ELSE
            BreakHours / 2
    END HoursOnBreak
FROM (
    SELECT
        [ID],
        [Employee-ID],
        [Date],
        [Coming-time],
        [Leaving-time],
        [Break(in hours)] AS BreakHours,
        CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Coming-time] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartDateTime,
        CASE
            WHEN [Coming-time] <= [Leaving-time] THEN 
                CAST([Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
            ELSE
                CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, [Date]) AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Leaving-time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
        END AS EndDateTime
    FROM
        [sandbox].[dbo].[TblEmployee]
) AS secondDay
```

After this you just slap on some aggregation and whamo. Want to aggregate by different time period, just change the group by to match your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Employee-ID, MONTH, SUM(WorkingHour)
FROM
(
SELECT  employee-ID,
        MONTH(date) as month,
        cast(DATEDIFF(HOUR,cast(coming-time as time),cast(leaving-time as time ))as float) -cast(break as float) as WorkingHour
FROM TABLENAME
)
GROUP BY Employee-ID,MONTH
ORDER BY Employee-ID,MONTH
```

The idea is like this.

Comment: Thank you for the help, your query helped me a lot, but I am still getting a wrong values even I tried like you with the using of cast, how can I get a true values for the hours difference ....

Comment: Cast to float is the key, as there are some floating number you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907459/how-to-get-the-total-working-hours-for-employees-with-sql-server#comment137081746_77756446

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    [Employee-ID] as employee_id,
          MONTH(Date) as month,
          SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [Coming-time], [Leaving-time]) / 60 - [Break]) as working_time

FROM      table_name

GROUP BY  [Employee-ID],
          MONTH(Date)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907459/how-to-get-the-total-working-hours-for-employees-with-sql-server#comment137081746_77756446

Answer (score 0):

hacker rank sql advanced
problem Weekend Hours Worked

query of mysql

```
SELECT emp_id,SUM(
           CASE
               WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, login_time, logout_time) > 0
               THEN FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, login_time, logout_time) / 60)
               ELSE 0
           END
       ) AS total_weekend_hours_worked
FROM (
    SELECT emp_id,
           MIN(timestamp) AS login_time,
           MAX(timestamp) AS logout_time
    FROM attendance
    WHERE DAYOFWEEK(timestamp) IN (1, 7) -- Considering Sunday (1) and Saturday (7) as weekends
    GROUP BY emp_id, CAST(timestamp AS DATE)
) AS weekend_hours
GROUP BY emp_id
ORDER BY total_weekend_hours_worked DESC;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Please use the code in the question. And use SQL Server syntax. Also, if this is quoted from hackerrank you *have* to refer to the source, otherwise it's plagiarism.